# Android Development: How Can I Make An EditText Plain So It's Just A White Square?

Tags: android, view, android-edittext

As the title says, I've seen EditTexts where they are just plain white with no smooth corners or orange android border when you highlight it etc.

Like it looks in this app:
http://s1.appbrain.com/screen?id=-2631427781674403509&i=1

Comment: you can use a white image in the background of EditTexts.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to create a custom background 9-patch image like this [one](http://i.piccy.info/i5/48/84/798448/white_bg.9.png) and put it to `/res/drawable` directory. Here is the [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) for 9-patch images. Then you need to apply the image as a background for your `EditText` using `android:background` attribute.

Here is a sample layout xml:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/white_bg"
    android:text="Test"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dip" /> 

<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/white_bg"
    android:text="Currently focused" />
```

And here is the result:

[image]