# How to make rounded TextView in Android?

Tags: android

I am developing an android application.In my application,I want to display paragraph string in TextView,so I want to rounded Textview look like given bellow. Textview shout be center position of the screen same like given bellow.How is possible?

[image]

Thanks Friends.

Comment: If I understand you correct, this should help:
http://androidforums.com/developer-101/194627-creating-text-boxes-rounded-edges.html

Answer (score 3):

I've just [answered on a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353265/android-development-how-can-i-make-an-edittext-plain-so-its-just-a-white-square/4353514#4353514).

The difference will be to use similar to [this image](http://i.piccy.info/i7/c57b44f315f8da44f09957845694c0ae/1-5-8912/27276354/toast_frame.9.png) as a background (probably it should a bit more transparent).

Comment: you dropbox link returns a 404.