# Android check editable value for EditText object

Tags: android, android-edittext

How can you get and set the editable value (true/false) of a EditText object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is combination of the properties `getFocusable` and `getEnabled`, though in some cases it might be that just `getEnabled` can do the trick for you.

Comment: yeah, that's exactly what i was thinking 10 seconds ago ... I think i'll revert to just disabling the edit text.... though i would have liked it to remain on a white background, and not turn grey...

Answer (score 2):

Try this (but there might be a better approach):

To prevent someone editing content in the EditText:

```
EditText comment = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_comment);
comment.setEnabled(false);
```

make it editable:

```
comment.setEnabled(true);
```

Then to check whether it's editable:

> comment.isEnabled()

Comment: i was hoping to keep the white background....but i think i'll do this instead....

Answer (score 1):

An `EditText` is always editable. There is no way to get the editable value from a `EditText`.

Answer (score 1):

In Android `EditText` does not operate with "editable" concept. Instead, in addition to "focusable"/"non-focusable", it can be "enabled"/"disabled":

```
boolean EditText.isEnabled()
void EditText.setEnabled(boolean enabled)
```

Comment: @AndreiBogdan: As to a white background (or any other custom background) you may find this interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4353514/247013